# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'regplot' on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Please I really need help with this error i keep getting. I have been find it difficult to make a plot with seaborn. Whenever i tried using the code i import seaborn as it gives me the same error as shown in the image link below. I have tried using conda install all over again but i keep getting the same error. Please what else can I do? Thank you

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFGF7.jpg)

Comment: There might be something wrong with your `seaborn` library. Try reinstall it.

Comment: Thank you but How can I do that without affecting my other anaconda installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an older version of the `seaborn`. Try to reinstall using `pip install seaborn --upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you but i tried upgrading it with pip install seaborn -- upgrade but I keep getting this error **(Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade from versions:) No matching distribution found for upgrade** each time i tried it. Should I uninstall Anaconda to resolve this or what do you think i can do? Would really appreciate your response. Thank you

Comment: hmm.. interesting.. I tried on my machine and I had no problem with that.. Can you tell me your system + anaconda specs? You can try to reinstall anaconda and then do `conda install seaborn` as well.

Comment: DELL XPS L502 , Anaconda 1.6.2. Can I just remove the anaconda and reinstall another one then install seaborn?

Comment: @Abiodun that’s probably the best solution at this point. Try that!

Comment: will try that and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you .. it's working now after uninstalling the version I have and reinstalling a new Anaconda. Thanks for your help.